# Need a better workaround for BadRequestError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, paging, app-engine-ndb

This is how I deal with:

```
BadRequestError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query
```

**Background:**
My application handles items. Each item has an owner and a datestring.
It runs in two parts, first checking existing items (from previous runs), comparing them to the once stored in NDB (sets datestring). Afterwards it handles all the once without updated datesting; with the function full_run.

```
#runs as a deferred task
def full_run(ownerKey, run_date):
  query = Item.query(ndb.AND(
    Item.owner == ownerKey, 
    ndb.OR(Item.push_date < run_date, Item.push_date > run_date)
  )).order(Item.push_date, Item._key)
  more = True
  curs = None
  while more:
    ndb_keys, curs, more = query.fetch_page(page_size=1000, start_cursor=curs, keys_only=True)
    deferred.defer(handle_key_page, ndb_keys, run_date)

def handle_key_page(key_page, run_date):
  for item in ndb.get_multi(key_page):
    deferred.defer(do_stuff, item)
    item.push_date = run_date
    item.put()
```

**Problem:**
When a query-item changes, the page-cursor becomes invalid.
This workaround utilize that tasks rerun when errors are raised. The new run will fetch a new set of 1000 (max:page_size) entries as the updated items get excluded from the future queries.

Two issues has become painfully clear:

¤ Tasks has exponential backoff so the time it takes to finish increase exponentially. (hard to debug)

¤ I handle errors (in do_stuff) by resetting the datesting. I first thought of this as an minor issue as I thought it ok if a few items in 1000 was handled multiple times.

The two combined is making this solution less scalable than I wish it to be but I haven't been able to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `_countdown` optional argument (in seconds) to `deferred.defer()` to delay executions of the `handle_key_page` jobs (which invalidate your query) just long enough to create and enqueue **all** those deferred jobs, which can then execute each at their own pace:

```
deferred.defer(handle_key_page, ndb_keys, run_date, _countdown=60)
```

You can even stagger jobs execution by enqueuing them with a progressively higher countdown - to keep activity peaks in check (if that's of interest to you).

Side note:

Switching from the deferred library to [push task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#push_queues) would offer some advantages:

- you can manually trigger the execution of a previously failed task before its normal exponentially backed off ETA, from the task queues menu in the admin page (local devserver) or developer console (production GAE). This *might* be possible for deferred tasks as well as they're just tasks enqueued by the deferred library, only I'm not sure on which queue - check your task queue page.
- you can control the backoff policy, see [Retrying Failed Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/push/retrying-tasks) or you can even overwrite it completely (by setting the task retries to 0, catching the failures in the task handler and re-enqueueing the task as you see fit).